# NodeJS - how to write to a file all the console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, centos

On my CentOS 7.x server I am running Node (v6.7.0 and v0.10.36).

`forever start /home/www/html/server/mynode.js`

which runs following:

`/usr/bin/node /home/www/html/server/mynode.js`

CODE of mynode.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var url = require('url');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3004);
io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    try{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(db));           
    } catch(dis) {
      console.log(dis);
    }

  });
});
```

How do i tell NodeJS or Linux to keep log? So that i can listen whats going on by `tail -f /var/log/mynode.log` ?

Comment: `forever start /home/www/html/server/mynode.js > /var/log/mynode.log`, for example

Comment: I tried that but it does not log the real console.log but it logs only the forever events.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can overwrite your `console.log`

```
var fs = require('fs');

var trueLog = console.log;
console.log = function(msg) {
    fs.appendFile("/tmp/log.log", msg, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return trueLog(err);
        }
    });
    //trueLog(msg); //uncomment if you want logs
}
```

Just put this snippet on top of your nodejs code.

Comment: I have a heavy duty on the NodeJs script. If i use writeFile on heavy duty. My script will perform slow and it will make the service slow motion. Is there no other better way?

Comment: @YumYumYum
well, you could use a buffer and write once it reached some limit, or even use triggered writes. If you need some help with that, just leave a PM ;)

Comment: Sure, can you please EDIT in the ANSWER with buffer method and another with triggered writes method? So that i can test and do bench mark on your 3 methods.

Comment: If var msg is something else other than string it will throw an error
So you will need to add: msg = String(msg);
For example if msg = 3 it will throw "msg.replace is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

There's an option for capturing logs
`forever -o path/to/logfile start /home/www/html/server/mynode.js`

From the docs `-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE`

Comment: Same problem. -o only logs forever events not the nodejs myscript.js events. `info: socket.io started
warn: error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE`